# nodejs write files which do not open

Tags: node.js

```
let dataCer = '0�\u0007\u00060�\u0006��\u0003\u0002\u0001\u0002\u0002\u0010Q��\u0000����K��Z�Q��0\n\u0006\b*�\u0003\u0007\u0001\u0001\u0003\u00020�\u0001l1\u001e0\u001c\u0006\.............'
```

```
fs.writeFile('111.cer', dataCer);
```

```
let dataPdf = '%PDF-1.4\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<< \r\n/Length 9947\r\n/Filter /FlateDecode\r\n>>\r\nstream\r\nX��]�n#9p}���\u000f���\u0005\b\u0002X��<\'X \u001f�\u001b\u0010 \u0001���H�,6�R�Z�\u0014�N`�\n�T�t�ڼT\u0015���?ԋz��_�{IN_Bz�����O.............'
```

```
fs.writeFile('111.pdf', dataPdf);
```

The data `dataCer` and `dataPdf` I get from the application using the `GET` requests. I can only get this data in this encoding.
And now I need to save them as files.

Also, I will need to then save any data to the file in the same way (`zip`, `rar`, `png`, `jpeg`, ...).

When i use `fs.writeFile`, I get files that do not open.
`fs.writeFile`, can not keep the original state data, ignoring the encoding does not give me the desired result.

Please tell me how to get around this error?
Or which library can save data to any file in `node.js`, while ignoring the encoding?

Comment: where's `dataCer` values comes from?

Comment: `dataCer` and `dataPdf` I get from the application using the `axios.get`.
This data's i can't get in other encoding or in `buffer`.